# Accessing dbch_devicetype fails

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, usb

I have a piece of MS C++ (unmanaged) code that runs whenever a USB device is inserted or removed into my computer.  On Windows 7, this code runs fine.  On Windows 10, it throws an error.  What happens is that when a USB drive, or any other USB device for that matter, is inserted into my computer, the OnMyDeviceChange routine gets called 3 times; it is only called two (correct) times on Windows 7.  Anyways, on Windows 10, the first two times, the routine runs fine.  The third time it fails on this line: type.Format("%d",pHdr->dbch_devicetype);.  Does anyone know why?

Note: we now know that for the code that fails, pHdr is null.

Here is my code:

```
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_DEVICECHANGE, OnMyDeviceChange)//in BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CBCGPMDIFrameWnd)

    LRESULT CMainFrame::OnMyDeviceChange(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //return 0;//essentially comment out everything else
    PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR pHdr = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR)lParam;
    AddLogLine("1");
//  AfxMessageBox(pHdr->dbch_devicetype);
    PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE pDevInf = (PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE)pHdr;
    AddLogLine("2");
    CString type;
    type.Format("%d",pHdr->dbch_devicetype);
    AddLogLine("type = " + type);
    if(pHdr->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE)
    {
        UpdateDevice(pDevInf, wParam);
    }
    return 0;
}






//More relevant code:
struct _DEV_BROADCAST_HDR {     /* */
    DWORD       dbch_size;
    DWORD       dbch_devicetype;
    DWORD       dbch_reserved;
};

typedef struct  _DEV_BROADCAST_HDR      DEV_BROADCAST_HDR;
typedef         DEV_BROADCAST_HDR       DBTFAR* PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR;
```

Comment: @HansPassant: In my opinion, this code is fine.  The typedef and structs are in the header file.  Thats probably what mades it so ugly.  I can check the size, but what I'm really trying to figure out is: 1) why I'm getting this bogus call in the first place. 2) what can I do to keep from getting this call.

Comment: @Hans:  Sorry, I didn't mean to offend.  I don't have Visual Studio on the WIndows 10 box and I can only run the code in release mode (long story).  I'll do what I can to get you that info.

Comment: @HansPassant: for the code that fails, the pHdr is null.  I'm putting in a check for this, but knowing why it happens in the first place would be very valuable.  It might prevent future issues from occuring.